# 2 column documents in mathematica

Tags: layout, formatting, wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica can be used to write very nice documents. Does anyone know if it is possible to write documents with 2 columns? If so, can you provide some examples or links to other notebooks that show this style.

Comment: Not exactly two-columns, but related: [Creating "margin" graphics](http://ibnhconsulting.blogspot.com/2011/09/creating-margin-graphics-custom.html)

Answer (score 9):

I don't think any good implementation of multicolumns are supported in Mathematica - it's not really compatible with the structure of the notebook interface. The fact that publicon does not support proper multiple columns is probably a good hint that Mathematica does not.

[**Q:   Does Publicon support multi-column layout?**](http://www.wolfram.com/products/publicon/qa.html#columns)

> Publicon documents are
>   oriented toward a vertical scrolling paradigm much like HTML, rather
>   than a page-by-page configuration found in page-layout programs.
>   Multiple columns can be configured in tables, but not maintained as
>   flows. Publicon's focus is on document structure, allowing clean
>   translation to LaTeX or XML for submission to publishers. Publishers
>   can then use page-layout tools that exploit their own particular
>   formats to generate single- or double-column layouts to their own
>   specifications.

Although, of course, hacks like [Bilateral Cells](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Add-onsLinks/AuthorTools/PaletteInterface/MakeBilateralCells/CreatingBilateralCellsPalette.html) (part of the Author Tools package mentioned in Verbia's answer) and that below can be used.

Here's some code that generates a two column text cell that will resize the columns to the window size - but the text does not flow from one column to another. Once the cell is generated, you can type in it as per normal.

```
Cell[BoxData[
   GridBox[{{Cell["Column One:\nsome text", "Text"], 
      Cell["Column Two:\nmore text", "Text"]}}, ColumnsEqual -> True, 
    ColumnSpacings -> 2, ColumnAlignments -> Left, 
    ColumnWidths -> Dynamic[First[WindowSize /. Options[EvaluationNotebook[]]]/(2*18)]]], 
  "Text"] // CellPrint
```

[image: 2 col text]

Or you can have text on the left an input/output on the right

```
Cell[BoxData[GridBox[{
     {Cell["Column One:\nsome text", "Text"], Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"1", "+", "1"}]], "Input"]},
     {"\[SpanFromAbove]", Cell[BoxData["2"], "Output"]}}, 
    ColumnsEqual -> True, ColumnSpacings -> 2, ColumnAlignments -> Left, 
    ColumnWidths -> Dynamic[First[WindowSize /. Options[EvaluationNotebook[]]]/(2*18)]]], 
  "Text"] // CellPrint
```

[image: 2 col in/out]

Note that I've only done a dodgy conversion from pixels to em by dividing the former by 18. The true conversion will be system and font dependent. Also, just adding `CellLabel`s to the input and output cells does not work. So the `In[n]:=` `Out[n]=` might need to be added manually using a small middle column.

Finally, it should be possible to construct something like the bilateral cell code used by the author tools package that grabs a Text/MathCaption cell followed by an Input and Output cell and combines them into a two-column construction.

Comment: I guess if I can export to Latex and then use the 2 column style would be ok. I did not think of that possibility. Unfortunately I still haven't figured out how to correctly use cross references in mathematica so that it can be exported to latex. I emailed them as you suggested before but they have not answered. I think I'm just going to email the guys at wolfram. I hope someone answers. In any case, I guess it is not possible do create a 2 column document in mathematica. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Graphics and Inset can be used for layouts, for example:-

```
text = StringTake[ExampleData[{"Text", "Prufrock"}], {226, 931}];
columntext1 = StringTake[text, 350];
columntext2 = StringTake[text, {348, 706}];
column1 = Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {150, 210}], Black,
    Inset[TextCell[columntext1,
      LineSpacing -> {0, 16}, TextJustification -> 1],
     {0, 210}, {Left, Top}, {150, Automatic}]},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 150}, {0, 210}},
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 
         FontWeight -> "Plain", FontSize -> 13}];
column2 = Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {150, 210}], Black,
    Inset[TextCell[columntext2,
      LineSpacing -> {0, 16}, TextJustification -> 1],
     {0, 210}, {Left, Top}, {150, Automatic}]},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 150}, {0, 210}},
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 
         FontWeight -> "Plain", FontSize -> 13}];
image = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House2"}];
clippedimage = Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {500, 270}],
    Inset[image, {250, 170}, {Center, Center}, {512, 512}]},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, {0, 270}}, ImageSize -> 500];
Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {330, 400}],
  Inset[column1, {75, 295}, {Center, Center}, {150, 210}],
  Inset[column2, {255, 295}, {Center, Center}, {150, 210}],
  Inset[clippedimage, {165, 90}, {Center, Center}, {330, 179}]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 330}, {0, 400}}, ImageSize -> 330]
```

[image]

Comment: Chris, that seems good, but I don't think that would be very efficient to write documents. What I would like is a way of making mathematica print the document with 2 columns. In this case all we care about is adding content. Using a graphics object is just too much work.

Comment: @ jmlopez - Yes, not as efficient as word processing.  Using Graphics makes it a two stage process: 1. set the text and 2. run the page layout. Also, it's difficult to calculate where to break the text for the two columns.  But aside from that it's a useable process.

Comment: Of relevance for automation: [measuring text box height](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10065/363).

Answer (score 4):

This apparently used to be possible using the [AuthorTools](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Add-onsLinks/AuthorTools/WhatIsAuthorTools.html) package for version 5 (see [this  reference in the Mathematica users wiki](http://www.mathematica-users.org/webMathematica/wiki/wiki.jsp?pageName=Notebook%3aTips.nb)).

However, there is no such palette in version 8, and neither the "Writing Assistant" palette nor the Option Inspector seem to have a relevant option.

It might be possible to do something using `Grid` with text-style `Cells` inside it, but I doubt it would be straightforward.

Comment: Here's a link with [Bilateral Cells](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Add-onsLinks/AuthorTools/PaletteInterface/MakeBilateralCells/CreatingBilateralCellsPalette.html) showing what used to be possible...

Comment: I thought about using `Grid` but like you said, it may not be straight forward. All I want to do is obtain the same styles as some journals. I hope there is an example for MMA8 showing how to create 2 columns with text, math formulas and sample code in there.