# Mathematica: Layout with Image and Text

Tags: pdf, printing, export, wolfram-mathematica

Any help is appreciated !

I have a lot of images and text that goes with each image. Now I would like to automatically generate the following handout for each pair of image and text:

[image]

- The image is on top.
- The text should be placed below it, its style    should be
  "justified" and if possible hyphenation enabled.
- Then the rest of the space should be an area, with a title names:
  "Notes", to    obviously take notes.

How can I do it with mathematica ?

Here are some images to try:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o8x992dz9gg7q9e/AAAyli1pO2f4q35ULNDreC1ua?dl=0

Here is the sample text that could go with it:

```
text={{"As there are several possibilities to perform lithography,", "I will start by providing some definitions", "and by explaining some general concepts that are recurring for all", "the lithography variations.", "Then I will dive into details how one fabricates the lithography masks", "using a direct write laser tool."},{"Lithography is the fundamental process of transferring geometric shape", "from a design to a thin layer of radiation sensitive material", "called resist.", "Which is covering the surface of a wafer substrate.", "These shapes or patterns define the various regions", "in an integrated circuit, such as the implantation regions,", "the contact windows, the metallic wiring etc."},{"Each lithography follows a well defined series of process steps,","called process flow.", "It may vary according to the lithography used", "and the materials involved.", "But a typical generic example is shown here", "where we go step by step through it.", "First the substrate, it can be a silicon wafer or glass plate,"}}
```

This is what I tried:

```
Labeled[images[[#]], Framed[text[[#]]], 
   LabelStyle -> 
    Directive[Bold, Alignment -> TextJustification, 
     Hyphenation -> False, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]] & /@ 
 Range[Length[images]]
```

Things that I don't know how to do:

1. Adding the extra box for notes
2. A4 size
3. Make image and text appropriate sizes
4. Hyphenation does not seem to work correctly either

Comment: This is a reliable approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7138184/879601

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach.  First set your print area for your chosen output.  PDF margins may differ from direct printing from Mathematica.  Note, due to setting `$FrontEndSession` these settings only persist for the current session.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintingOptions -> {
    "PrintingMargins" -> {
      {10(* position left *), 40(* clip right *)},
      {30(* clip bottom *), 25(* position top *)}},
    "FirstPageHeader" -> False,
    "FirstPageFooter" -> False,
    "RestPagesHeader" -> False,
    "RestPagesFooter" -> False,
    "Magnification" -> 1}];

testpage = Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {700, 1080}], Black,
    Line[{{0, 0}, {700 - 1, 0}, {700 - 1, 1080}, {0, 1080}, {0, 0}}]},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 700}, {0, 1080}}, ImageSize -> 700];

nb = CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[testpage, "Print"], WindowSize -> 850];
Export[FileNameJoin[{$InitialDirectory, "testpage.pdf"}], nb];
NotebookClose[nb]
```

[image]

Using one of the OP's images, and text, modified to include a hyphen for line-wrap demonstration.

```
image = Import[FileNameJoin[{$InitialDirectory, "p1.jpg"}]];

text1 = StringRiffle[StringReplace[StringRiffle[#, " "], {". " -> ".  ",
       "some definitions" -> "some-definitions"}] & /@ Most@text, "\n\n"];
```

Page creation function.

```
createPage[{image_, text_, number_, pdfname_}] := Module[{y = -200},
  page = Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {700, 1080}], Black,

     Inset[image, {0, 1080}, {Left, Top}, {700, Automatic}],

     Inset[
      Graphics[{Blue, Thickness[0.005],
        Line[{{0, 600 + 1 + y}, {700 - 1, 600 + 1 + y},
          {700 - 1, 800 + y}, {0, 800 + y}, {0, 0}}],
        Black,
        Inset[
         TextCell[text, LineSpacing -> {0, 16}, TextJustification -> 1],
         Center, Center, {600, Automatic}]
        },
       PlotRange -> {{0, 700}, {600 + y, 800 + y}}, ImageSize -> 700,
       BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times",
         FontWeight -> "Plain", FontSize -> 15.5}],
      {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {700, Automatic}],

     Inset[
      Graphics[{
        Red,
        Line[{{570, 100 + 1}, {630 - 1, 100 + 1},
          {630 - 1, 160}, {570, 160}, {570, 100 + 1}}],
        Black,
        Inset[ToString[number], Center, Center, Automatic]
        },
       PlotRange -> {{570, 630}, {100, 160}}, ImageSize -> 60,
       BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times",
         FontWeight -> "Plain", FontSize -> 32}],
      {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {60, Automatic}]
     },
    PlotRange -> {{0, 700}, {0, 1080}}, ImageSize -> 700,
    BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times",
      FontWeight -> "Plain", FontSize -> 15.5}];

  nb = CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[page, "Print"], WindowSize -> 850]; 
  Export[FileNameJoin[{$InitialDirectory, pdfname}], nb]; 
  NotebookClose[nb]]

createPage[{image, text1, 4, "page.pdf"}]
```

[image]

Note. The `+1` and `-1` adjustments are only for on-screen rendering.  They can be omitted for printing or conversion to PDF.

**Estimating text block height**

If your text insets vary in height from page to page the layout can be adjusted programmatically using this routine.  Note, this is approximate because it is operating in the `"Working"` [screen style environment](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScreenStyleEnvironment.html) whereas PDF or printing uses the `"Printout"` environment which differs slightly.  For example, the first paragraph wraps onto four lines in the `"Printout"` environment.

```
makebox[wd_, ht_] := Graphics[{Green, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {wd, ht}],
   Black, Inset[
    TextCell[text1, LineSpacing -> {0, 16}, TextJustification -> 1],
    {0, 0}, {Left, Bottom}, {wd, Automatic}]},
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times",
    FontWeight -> "Plain", FontSize -> 15.5},
  PlotRange -> {{0, wd}, {0, ht}}, ImageSize -> wd]

box = makebox[600, 900];
raster = Rasterize[box, "Data"];
topline = raster[[1]] = raster[[2]];
newheight = Length[Reverse@raster /. {x__, topline ..} :> {x}] + 4;

Row[{"Text block pixel height is ", newheight}]
makebox[600, newheight]
```

[image]

**Multi-page PDF**

To publish multiple pages in a single PDF.

```
nb = CreateDocument[{
    ExpressionCell[page1, "Print"],
    ExpressionCell[page2, "Print"],
    ExpressionCell[page3, "Print"]}, WindowSize -> 850];
Export[FileNameJoin[{$InitialDirectory, "allpages.pdf"}], nb];
NotebookClose[nb]
```

Comment: That looks really nice !! Thanks a lot !!! Do you know how to export multiple image-text pairs each on a separat page (like presented here) , and all in one pdf ?

Comment: To publish multiple separate pages map the `createPage` function over lists of page parameters. For a multi-page PDF build multiple pages then export them in a single PDF as shown above.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is awesome ! :))

Comment: Thanks for the additional edit ! Maybe you are interested to see for what I need this kind of layout (not implemented yet): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159065/automatic-edx-pdf-handout-creator